# Is there a word for someone who forgets people's names?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that describes a person who is unable to remember people's names.
An example would be:

> You can't blame her though, she is a [forgetter of names].

In terms of a condition I found *aphasia*, which the OED defines as the "*loss of ability to understand or express speech, caused by brain damage*" but this isn't quite what I'm looking for.

Which word would be best suited?

Comment: absent-minded— *having or showing a habitually forgetful or inattentive disposition*. But that doesn't necessarily mean the person hasn't a memory for names. By placing *"she is an excellent __"*, you're making out it to be a virtue. I realize it's meant to be an ironic/sarcastic/teasing remark, but it will throw people off. I presume you're looking for a noun.

Comment: Good suggestion. I've edited it for clarity. In terms of _absent-minded_, I'm after something that would give an impression of someone who might actually try quite hard to remember names but still fails to do so - I'm not entirely sure _absent minded_ does the trick.

Comment: @Gordonium I have no idea, but after seeing the "aphasia“ you provided and combining it with my limited knowledge in Latin, I found a word just one step closer: anomia, more appropriately anomic aphasia. However, I might still not be close enough, as the word can refer to trouble remembering the names of anything, not necessarily people.

Comment: I have the same thing. I will get a job at a restaurant with maybe twenty employees, and it will take me months before I know everyone's names, though I see them daily. It is an aphasia of sorts, and I like the colloquial 'tortle' - but I'm not brain damaged. I Have been this way my whole life. And have learned to hide it well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Face blindness" is the non-technical term.

["prosopagnosia"](http://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2010/08/30/face-blind) is the technical term.

(I'm not including a quote since Sacks tends to write in a rambling style and there's not really one pithy quote to grab.)

Interestingly, people with face blindness also tend to have difficulty "navigating" -- they easily get lost if they don't have a map.

There are a number of [web resources](https://www.faceblind.org/links/index.html).

(FWIW, I have this disorder, apparently a "gift" from the polio I had at age 2.)

Comment: But this is the inability to recognize people's faces, not names. Is this the same thing? I think not, I may recognize a person's face as being familiar but be at a loss for their name—I've forgotten their names. But if the OP's happy...

Comment: @Mari-LouA - It's the same.  The portion of the brain which remembers names and faces (and places) is damaged.  The degree of damage varies, from being able to remember 20-100 names and "recognize" (but not name) a few hundred to not being able to remember anyone at all.

Comment: This certainly could explain some instances of (apparent) name-forgetting, but it doesn't sound like the author of the linked article actually had trouble with names; in the anecdote about his psychiatrist, for example, he fails to recognize the man at all *until he hears the man's name*. I think this is different from the experience @Mari-LouA describes, of knowing you know someone but being unable to access their name. Still a solid answer, though.

Comment: @1006a - The disorder spans a wide spectrum, from not recognizing your wife to being able to "pass" as "normal" since you only have difficulty remembering names of casual acquaintances.

Comment: I agree that pinning names to people, or any ascribing anything else for that matter, is part of the same problem. People with this condition tend to have a very different filing system for information. Whether this is actually related to the condition or just a side effect - I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

There was a segment on today's "Wait Wait Don't Tell Me," where they mentioned a Scottish word "tortle" which meant precisely - to blank on someone's name who you knew well.  As in:

"I was introducing my boyfriend to my best friend, and I tortled my best friend!"

Comment: Do you think you can find some reference, doesn't have to be a dictionary, though that would be good, where the definition is written down? Or maybe you can find the written transcript of the show?

Comment: The word is *tartle*: https://dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/tartle_v1_n1

Answer (score 0):

*Anomia* is the condition in which someone forgets the names of things, and I'm told by a neurologist that it happens to affect proper nouns more than other nouns.